# Создать маршрут в camel

Tags: apache, маршрутизация

Задача стоит в Apache camel создать маршрут, который бы брал файлы из папки, удалял бы из каждого файла последнюю строку, а затем парсил. Часть с парсингом получилось реализовать, но как сделать удаление строки не могу понять.
Пример кода

```
<route id="generateOrder-route">
        <from uri="file:G://data?noop=true"/>

            <bean ref="orderBean" method="deleteString()"/>
            <log message="${body}" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="Test"/>
            <!--to uri="bean:orderBean?method=deleteString(${header.id})" /-->          

    </route>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ нашел.
Создаем в бине функцию удаления строки и вызываем ее с параметром абсолютного пути.

```
<bean ref="orderBean" method="deleteString(${file:absolute.path})"/>
```